# 64-Bit binary execution error on 64-Bit Centos

Tags: 64-bit, executable

While executing one of my C++ Application, I am getting a weird message on one of my Cento x64 box where at the same time another machine with similar configuration is perfectly running the Application.

Error message is:

**/myapp: error while loading shared libraries: /myapp: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64**

N.B: 'myapp' is not some shared library (.so) but actual application itself.

All 3rd party libs being linked with myapp have also been compiled on machine on which I am executing the application. I have compiled libmysqlpp, libthrift and libACE libraries and anything else necessary has been installed through yum.

Comment: What does `ldd myapp` gives you? Is everything resolved? Any warnings you got while compiling and linking `myapp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is resolved.

Actually I was trying to load my application dynamically using **ld-linux.so.2** in order to make use of custom library folder but ld-linux.so.2 only executes 32-Bit binaries. Now I am using **ld-linux-x86-64.so.2** and everything seems good :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an excellent in depth article on the wider topic (e.g. running 32 bit compiled apps on 64 bit machines) over at http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/534 titled "Running 32-bit Applications on 64-bit Debian GNU/Linux".  The short answer is the [ia32 Suite](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=ia32-libs).